# SEO friendly URL rewrite and folders

Tags: apache, iis, url-rewriting

I am using URL rewrite on Winwdows IIS and Linux Apache to get better looking URL-s. The URL rewriting itself works perfectly, but if I want to access some folders on that domain or in the folder where URL-s are rewritten, web-server rewrites the folder name as well and sends the request to my referred php file.

For example if I have mydomain.com/somesite/about, it becomes mydomain.com/somesite/index.php?one=about. But if I want to access a folder called "somefolder" (that actually exists) at mydomain.com/somesite/somefolder, then the only way is to refer to an exact file in that folder (mydomain.com/somesite/somefolder/index.php), because otherwise it is being rewritten to mydomain.com/somesite/index.php?one=somefolder

Could someone please give me an example on how to get the URL-s rewritten and as well access folders without referring to specific files.

Here is my Apache .htaccess:

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewriterule ^([\w\-]+)/?$ index.php?one=$1
Rewriterule ^([\w\-]+)/([\w\-]+)/?$ index.php?one=$1&two=$2
Rewriterule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ index.php?one=$1&two=$2&three=$3
Rewriterule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ index.php?one=$1&two=$2&three=$3&four=$4 
</IfModule>
```

And here is my IIS web.config:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="one" enabled="true">
                    <match url="^(\w+)/?$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/somesite/index.php?one={R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="two" enabled="true">
                    <match url="^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/somesite/index.php?one={R:1}&amp;two={R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="three" enabled="true">
                    <match url="^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/somesite/index.php?one={R:1}&amp;two={R:2}&amp;three={R:3}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="four" enabled="true">
                    <match url="^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/somesite/index.php?one={R:1}&amp;two={R:2}&amp;three={R:3}&amp;four={R:4}" />
                </rule>
    
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do SEO friendly url, I suggest to develop a routing component,  next step how to to this.

### Apache config

You should use this rewrite configuration

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]
```

I explain this line step by step

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` condition : all requests that matches an existing regular file in document root

`RewriteRule .* - [QSA,L]` A dash indicates that no substitution should be performed, the existing path, **.***, is passed through untouched

This rewriteRule is just after a rewriteCond, so rewriteCond apply only to this rewrite rule

The last but not the least :
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]` redirect all requests that don't match previous rewrite rule to file index.php

there are some flag in rewrite rule

- **[QSA]** : Appends any query string from the original request URL to any query string created in the rewrite target
- **[L]** : Stop the rewriting process immediately and don't apply any more rules

### PHP

Now, all your requests except real file are redirect to index.php

In your file index.php, you can add this code

```
<?php
var_dump($_SERVER);
var_dump($_GET);
```

### Test

It's time to test, if it's well configure, you can try some request like

- `http://example.com/somesite/somefolder`
- `http://example.com/somesite/anotherfolder?param=value`

You should see var_dump of $_SERVER and $_GET 
If you want to develop a simple router, you can use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI]

It's just a very very very simple router for example

```
<?php

$rawRoute = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);


switch($rawRoute[1]){
        case 'blog':    echo "this is blog page";
                        break;
        case 'forum':   echo "this is forum page";
                        break;
        default:        echo "no route matches, redirect to 404";
                        break;


}
```

You can look to this repository https://github.com/dannyvankooten/PHP-Router for understand how to work a router, if you're more reckless, you can look at symfony routing.